# Import header and footer in html

Tags: html

I recently started learning HTML and I created some HTML files (pages), and I want to make my code shorter now. I want to make a html file where I write the header code, and a html file where I write my footer code. Is there a way I could import then these 2 files in all my other html files? If yes, could you please refer me to the learning page :D?

Comment: @beresfordt i tried <link rel="import" href="header.html">, I don't know if it is the code for that, but I read it somewhere in some page... hope Im not making a total fool of myself^^

Comment: @EtritBujupi I think you will need to use php, you could load the content in an iframe and always use the html file with the header and footer attached.

Comment: @etritbujupi Personally I didn't know about `rel="import"`, but a quick search led me to [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/), so it is an existing feature that might work for this purpose and you're not making a fool out of yourself. But if you found something like that and tried it, it's good to mention that in your question and describe what the outcome of your experiment was. That way you prevent that people waste their time explaining stuff that you already found out.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) could guide you but is not so-well currently supported.
 Also, you have to make a lot of js work.

As @Austin Collins suggest, you should look for a technology that make such dinamic behavior  like php, asp, jsp, but then again, It has theirs downsides (learning curve).

Comment: I didn't see the comment of @etritbujupi before sending this answer. So, sorry, wasn't my intention to plagiarize an advice